# Alternatives to GameObject.Find();

Tags: unity-game-engine

I am trying to load different levels in my puzzle game, but when I hide the levels that aren't being used, `GameObject.Find();` does not work. Is there a way to substitute this function for one that can find objects that are hidden?

Comment: Why not do something that makes an list of list of objects or dictionary of list of objects so your objects are all active you find all the things split them into their levels and just use that reference later

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, it's pretty dirty but if you don't have a previous reference to the object, you can use [this](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Resources.FindObjectsOfTypeAll.html?_ga=2.199224683.514809683.1591267105-1751818090.1485189056) method under Resources class: `public static T[] FindObjectsOfTypeAll();`

From the docs example:

> Contrary to Object.FindObjectsOfType this function will also list
>   **disabled** objects.

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEditor;

public class ExampleScript : MonoBehaviour
{
    List<GameObject> GetAllObjectsOnlyInScene()
    {
        List<GameObject> objectsInScene = new List<GameObject>();

        foreach (GameObject go in Resources.FindObjectsOfTypeAll(typeof(GameObject)) as GameObject[])
        {
            if (!EditorUtility.IsPersistent(go.transform.root.gameObject) && !(go.hideFlags == HideFlags.NotEditable || go.hideFlags == HideFlags.HideAndDontSave))
                objectsInScene.Add(go);
        }

        return objectsInScene;
    }
}
```